# Oracle APEX preload audio files

Tags: javascript, oracle, audio, oracle-apex, preload

I have an Oracle Apex application running on a Android device, which some specific sounds need to be played on multiples pages when a button is clicked, e.g. A notification..

The way I did it is, create the audio object on the header of the page,

```
var audio = new Audio('/path/Alert.mp3');
```

And trigger the play event when a button is clicked,

```
$('#btn_alert').click(function(){     
  audio.play();
})
```

This doesn't work as expected for 2 reasons,

1. When the button gets clicked for the first time, there always a delay before the sound gets played, seems like the page is loading the file or somehow. And from the second time onwards, the sound gets played immediately (looks like its been cached). How do I preload the audio file on a mobile device?
2. Is there anyway to define the audio object in global scope, so I don't have to repeat the same code on every page?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you add and item to a Global Page - a specific type of page - it will be available on all pages in the APEX application. More [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3934861), and in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/ui_allpgs.htm#HTMDB28490).

WRT to the audio, [this](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/item-plugin/audio-player-item_99.html) may help. Also you might try a [dynamic action](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/advnc_dynamic_actions.htm#HTMDB27020) on page load to load the file.